# react - left corner logo list of links off center with inline

Tags: html, css, reactjs, inline

I am trying to have a list of links centered in the middle of the page. using this setup, it is slightly to the right, why is this the case? I think that my left corner logo is pushing them off-center, as the logo, list of links, and profile link are all on the same horizontal plane. However, I want the links to be centered regardless of how big the logo is. How can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';

function CornerPiece(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      { props.value}
    </div>
  )
}

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="menu-outer">
        <div class="alignleft">
          <CornerPiece
            value={<h2>ThisIsMyLogo</h2>} /></div>
        <div class="alignright">
          <CornerPiece
            value={<h3>Profile</h3>} /></div>
        <div id="navcontainer">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
h1, h2,  h3,  a {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;

}

#navcontainer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2%;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:center;
  }

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
  }

.alignleft {
    padding-left: 2%;
    float: left;
  }

.alignright {
    padding-right: 2%;
    float: right;
  }
```

Comment: you can try flexbox for alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**

I updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mahavira-581z7). Please check it.

1. I changed order of elements in `menu-outer`
2. I removed `float` in all child elements of `menu-outer` and gave them `flex: 1`
3. I added

   #menu-outer {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   }
4. `.alignright` also has `text-align: right`

Why I removed `float` and added `flex`? This approach it is better to handle block elements in horizontal line.

Also I would offer you to forget about padding with **%**, in terms of UI it is better to use numbered paddings (10px, 20px, or even better 16px and 32px)

**Previous reply**

I tried your example and it works fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-glitter-6y3sd). This means that problem is not in this part of code, but somewhere in parent component.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added a bit more details to the question, maybe that would be helpful for you. Thanks again!